# Assign threads to run on a custom Core in Unix

Tags: unix, parallel-processing

Is it possible to run a particular thread/process on any core we want?
 Since multi-core systems are available today . Is it possible to assign two (mutually independent ) segments of code run on any core we want to rather than wait for it to be assigned in a round robin fashion?
This way we can truly reap the benefits of parallel processing.

Is there a system call in the **Unix flavours** that lets us assign threads to specific cores?

Comment: As @ennuikiller said, the magic words are 'processor affinity'; Google search on that will yield what you want.  AFAICT, POSIX does not formally standardize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sometimes achieve this with utilizing processor affinity on linux systems.  [This is a detailed description of what can be done and how to do it.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-affinity.html)